# Play .avi video using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have some .avi video files. But they can not read by python-OpenCV. Please expert help me to read them.

my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

video_name = input("\"Ch14_20211020000000_20211025235959_2.avi\":\n")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)

time_length = 30.0
fps=25
frame_seq = 749
frame_no = (frame_seq /(time_length*fps))

cap.set(2,frame_no);

ret, frame = cap.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

my_video_name = video_name.split(".")[0]

cv2.imshow(my_video_name+' frame '+ str(frame_seq),gray)

cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imwrite(my_video_name+'_frame_'+str(frame_seq)+'.jpg',gray)


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: insufficient. please review [ask] and [mre]. you haven't shown any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is here itself

```py
video_name = input("\"Ch14_20211020000000_20211025235959_2.avi\":\n")
```

change that to

```py
video_name = r'Ch14_20211020000000_20211025235959_2.avi'
```

Comment: Thank u.. i tried like that also. But its give nothing

Comment: can you share that video ? so I can look into it ?

Comment: Sorry sir. Those videos are very privet. So I can not give. any other information do you need I can give.